# Tkinter Binding

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, key-bindings

My problem with binding appears when I bind <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F5</kbd> in a tk top level frame. Everything is going fine in the computer I'm programming, but when someone presses the bound keys in other computers nothing happens or the help from Windows comes up. I've been looking for info, but I haven't been able to find someone with the same problem.

The code of the binding:

```
self.master.bind('<F2>', self.eventoModificarCant)
self.master.bind('<F3>', self.eventoQuitarProducto)
self.master.bind('<F4>', self.eventoNotaGeneral)
self.master.bind('<F5>', self.eventoNotaProducto)
self.master.bind('<F6>', self.eventoPedido)
```

There's one more bind but it is not there, still the same code structure.

UPDATE:
I programmed it in Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits(6.1 compilation 7601) and currently I'm trying to run it in Windows 7 Proffesional 32 bits(6.1 compilation 7601)-Thank you for pointing that useful info @Bryan Oakley

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: When you say "other computers", are they the same OS, or is this a problem where it works on linux but not on windows (or visa versa)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I programmed it in Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits(6.1 compilation 7601) and currently I'm trying to run it in Windows 7 Proffesional 32 bits(6.1 compilation 7601)